# How can i insert object which got arrays into arrays using jq?

Tags: json, jq

I may not discribed it properly, I tried many times and looked up the manaual on [jq Manaual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) , and i got no idea how to insert object which contains array into a json file by jq command, anyway,  here is the origin test.json:

```
[
  {
    "gate": [
      {
        "pro1": "1"
      }
    ],
    "home": [
      {
        "mem1": "1"
      }
    ],
    "holder": "1"
  }
]
```

And i wish to be like this after insert:

```
[
  {
    "gate": [
      {
        "pro1": "1"
      }
    ],
    "home": [
      {
        "mem1": "1"
      }
    ],
    "holder": "1"
  },
  {
    "gate": [
      {
        "pro1": "2"
      }
    ],
    "home": [
      {
        "mem1": "2"
      }
    ],
    "holder": "1"
  }
]
```

Could it possibly done by jq?

Comment: where do values `"pro1": "2"` and ` `"mem1": "2"` come from? are they statically hardcoded, or are increments from over the first (original) record?

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided more detail I am going to assume that you simply want to append a hard-coded object to an existing array. (If that's not what you mean you'll need to be more precise in your question.)

You can add items to the end of a list with the `+` operator. So in your case:

```
jq '.+[{"gate":[{"pro1": "2"}], "home":[{"mem1": "2"}],"holder": "1"}]' input.json
```

```
[
  {
    "gate": [
      {
        "pro1": "1"
      }
    ],
    "home": [
      {
        "mem1": "1"
      }
    ],
    "holder": "1"
  },
  {
    "gate": [
      {
        "pro1": "2"
      }
    ],
    "home": [
      {
        "mem1": "2"
      }
    ],
    "holder": "1"
  }
]
```

The `.` takes the existing input, which is an array. The `+[ {...} ]` concatenates it with another array of one object. If you want to put the new item(s) at the start instead of the end, swap it round: `[ {...} ]+.`